# Using jq, how can I flatten to tsv and have nested array flattened as comma delimited value?

Tags: array, jq

I have the following JSON format:

```
{
"page":1,
"total_results":1,
"total_pages":1,
"results":[
    {
    "id":6037,
    "genre_ids":[35,80,9648,53],
    "popularity":11.379
    }
]
}
```

I need to produce this format, where the genre_ids array are comma separated and don't add tabs to the horizontal spacing:

```
6037   35,80,9648,53   11.379
```

I have been able to flatten the results array with:

```
jq -r '.results[0] | [.id,.popularity] | @tsv'
```

Which results in:

```
6037   11.379
```

But if I add the genre_ids:

```
jq -r '.results[0] | [.id,.genre_ids[],.popularity] | @tsv'
```

I get:

```
308531   28   12   35   878   10751   32.497
```

How can I get the `genre_ids` array to flatten into a comma separated list within the tab separated parent elements?

Answer (score 3):

You can [`join`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#join(str)) the array into a string:

```
$ jq -r '.results[0] | [.id,(.genre_ids | join(",")),.popularity] | @tsv' < foo.json
6037    35,80,9648,53   11.379
```

Answer (score 1):

```bash
jq -r '.results[] | [ .id, (.genre_ids|@csv), .popularity ] | @tsv' file
```

This reformats the `genre_ids` array into a CSV formatted record before making it part of the tab-delimited output.

The output, given the data in the question, would be

```
6037    35,80,9648,53   11.379
```

If the `results` array contains multiple elements, each element would be formatted as its own line of output.

Example of what the output would look like given more elements in the `results` array:

```bash
$ cat file
{
   "page": 1,
   "results": [
      {
         "genre_ids": [ 3, 8, 964, 5 ],
         "id": 6000,
         "popularity": 12
      },
      {
         "genre_ids": [ 35, 80, 9648, 53 ],
         "id": 6037,
         "popularity": 11.379
      }
   ],
   "total_pages": 1,
   "total_results": 2
}
```

```bash
$ jq -r '.results[] | [ .id, (.genre_ids|@csv), .popularity ] | @tsv' file
6000    3,8,964,5       12
6037    35,80,9648,53   11.379
```